# How to include file in Source Control and edit it later

Tags: c#, tfs, azure-devops

I'm creating a game using C# and trying to incorporate a CSV for parsing previous scores into a leaderboard and also writing to the file when a player finishes their game.

This is the data stored relating to a score

[image]

If this was a sole project I would store the csv in the bin > Debug folder and pass the file path to a StreamReader. Although, this is a group project using Azure Devops/TFS as source control so I'm not too sure what way is best to do this.

I have tried storing the CSV in the Resources of the project but I didn't realise this embeds the file in the project and only allows for reading from the file.

The CSV is currently read like:

```
var file = Properties.Resources.highscores;
char[] splitter = "\r\n".ToCharArray();
string[] scoresCsv = Properties.Resources.highscores.Split(splitter);

foreach (string score in scoresCsv)
{
    if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(score))
    {
        var values = score.Split(',');
        highScores.Add(new HighScore(values[0], Convert.ToInt32(values[1]), Convert.ToDateTime(values[2])));
    }
}
this.highScores = highScores.OrderByDescending(x => x.Score).ToList();
```

Comment: Bit confused by this. Is the high score file supposed shared by different people? So when they get a new high score they check in the file, and everyone else sees it when they do a pull from source control?

Answer (score 0):

Select the "Team Explorer" window and go to "Source Control Explorer"

Here you will see a global view of the project.

You can add files to your project in any folder you wish outside of the actual source. If you want to you can add your bin folder into the source control and keep that file in the bin folder.

Where-ever you put the file you just need to know the location to it from your project and you are able to map to it and edit it in runtime.

Another option is to create a folder in the C:\ProgramData folder for your game and you can write the leaderboards directly into their C drive when they run the game. People would be able to modify the leaderboards but, obviously the game is for learning purposes of coding and usually you wouldn't store the leaderboards on the client side anyway it would be on a server.

Comment: _"add your bin folder into the source control"_ don't do that.

Comment: Why not exactly? @stuartd It will update everytime you rebuild your solution and the last build will be readily available in your source?

Comment: It's just not good practise - source control should contain what you need to build the app, not the output build. Also -  _"It will update everytime you rebuild your solution and the last build will be readily available in your source"_ no it won't - it will update when you check in your changes.

Answer (score 0):

This assumes that the high score data is not shared, and stores it locally. It doesn't require the file to be added to source control.

```cs
public class ScoreFileHandler
{
    private static string appPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "YourAppName");
    private static string scoreFileName = "highscores.txt";
    private static string filePath = Path.Combine(appPath, scoreFileName);

    public string ReadFile()
    {
        if (!Directory.Exists(appPath))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(appPath);
        }

        if (File.Exists(filePath))
        {
            return File.ReadAllText(filePath);
        }

        return string.Empty; // TODO - caller needs to handle this
    }

    public void WriteFile(string csvScoreData)
    {
        if (!Directory.Exists(appPath))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(appPath);
        }

        File.WriteAllText(filePath, csvScoreData);
    }
}
```